# Oracle ORDS (19.x) with Tomcat 9.X Application at context path [/ords] could not be started : java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException

Tags: tomcat, oracle-rest-data-services

When I try to start the ORDS from tomcat manager it says: " *Application at context path [/ords] could not be started*"

The catalina.log says :

```
...
SEVERE [http-nio-8081-exec-3] . java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/oracle/ords/params/ords
java.lang.IllegalStateException: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /home/oracle/ords/params/ords
    at oracle.dbtools.common.pools.legacy.ConfigurationFilesBase.ensureDefaultsExist(ConfigurationFilesBase.java:205)
    at oracle.dbtools.common.pools.legacy.ConfigurationFilesBase.<init>(ConfigurationFilesBase.java:48)
...
```

The /home/oracle/ords/params/ords directory, files and sub-directories have all the correct permissions.

On the same server I already have installed **Tomcat 6.x** and deployed **ORDS 19.x**, the ords.war I deployed is configured to a remote **APEX 4.x**.
The url http://myserver:8080/ords leads correctly to the Application Express Login page.
I'am trying to upgrade and make a cleaner config of the stack (tomcat is bundled under another app that also need an upgrade) so I install **Tomcat 9.x** (not bundled) and it is working fine at http://myserver:8081 . But trying to deploy the same ords.war the exception is raised.

Answer (score 0):

I answer my own question in order to close the thread. The only way I found to make it working is to :
undeploy the ords.war

- undeploy the ords.war
- remove the installation dir (unziped ords installation zip file)
- unzip the ords installation file at the same level of my tomcat directory (e.g. /opt/tomcat9, /opt/ords)
- proceed in the installation of ords following the documentation (java -jar ords.war install advanced)

Answer (score 0):

I did this to make it work:

- setup ORDS in standalone mode (use different port than Tomcat) just to be sure it works
- deploy ords.war to Tomcat and restart - it fails to start /ords application but it is deployed correctly (ords folder is created in webapps)
- create a folder in Tomcat root named ords\config
- copy everything from config folder of ORDS installation to this new folder
- change webapps\ords\WEB-INF\web.xml - update config.dir to this new folder
- restart Tomcat

APEX 19.2, ORDS 19.2, Tomcat 9